# cannot do slice indexing with these indexes error in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
                                   Date     Open     High      Low    Close        Volume
Date
2020-05-21 06:00:00 2020-05-21 06:00:00  9483.37  9532.39  9400.00  9457.83   8732.433715
2020-05-21 10:00:00 2020-05-21 10:00:00  9457.88  9505.57  9228.00  9389.97  20789.066523
2020-05-21 14:00:00 2020-05-21 14:00:00  9389.97  9395.43  8949.74  9084.38  35226.100321
2020-05-21 18:00:00 2020-05-21 18:00:00  9082.50  9135.09  8815.00  9065.53  25961.980448
2020-05-21 22:00:00 2020-05-21 22:00:00  9065.81  9164.99  9011.21  9068.65  11209.523919
```

I'm trying to slice it and get, for example, only the last 2 elements from the dataframe:

```
2020-05-21 18:00:00 2020-05-21 18:00:00  9082.50  9135.09  8815.00  9065.53  25961.980448
2020-05-21 22:00:00 2020-05-21 22:00:00  9065.81  9164.99  9011.21  9068.65  11209.523919
```

So i tried this:

```
print(df.loc[-2:])
```

But it gave me the following error:

```
cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [-2] of <class 'int'>
```

Why did i get this error? Is it because i need to set an index? Or am i using a wrong syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `iloc` (indexing by row number) instead of `loc` (indexing by index values, which in your case is the Date).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pick only last 2 rows from df, you can also use `df.tail(2)`:

```
df.tail(2)
```

OR:

```
df[-2:]
```